# Installing google play services from APKmirror by command line

Tags: apk, google-play-services

APKmirror provides many modern apps as split apk tar files. For example, if I want to install the android webview apk, I can download it from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/android-system-webview-88-0-4324-152-release/), and un-tar the `.apkm` file to produce the following split apk:

```
├── APKM_installer.url
├── META-INF
├── base.apk
├── icon.png
├── info.json
├── split_config.en.apk
├── split_config.es.apk
├── split_config.fi.apk
├── split_config.fr.apk
├── split_config.iw.apk
├── split_config.ja.apk
├── split_config.pt.apk
├── split_config.ru.apk
├── split_config.sv.apk
├── split_config.th.apk
└── split_config.zh.apk
```

This split apk can be installed with:

```
adb install-multiple -r -g -t <directory>/*.apk
```

However, for APKmirror's google play services found [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-21-02-14-release/google-play-services-21-02-14-000300-352619232-android-apk-download/), when I untar I get this:

```
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── META-INF
├── assets
├── build-data.properties
├── classes.dex
├── classes2.dex
├── classes3.dex
├── classes4.dex
├── classes5.dex
├── classes6.dex
├── classes7.dex
├── com
├── googledata
├── lib
├── org
├── res
├── resources.arsc
└── stamp-cert-sha256
```

This looks more like an `.aab` file, however it is missing the required `BundleConfig.pb` file.

What type of app format it this, and how can I turn it into a split apk that can be installed easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

1. This is apk app format
2. I can install by just renaming the download from `.apkm` to `.apk`.

Thanks to Robert for pointing this out!